# How to set arrays so php write xml file correctly

Tags: php, xml, api, href

I’m stuck, trying to figure out what code to put for the .php MY Question is what should be the arrays for the xml file especially the “href links”

```
       $xml = new DOMDocument ("1.0","UTF-8");

       $playlists = $xml -> createElement("playlists");
       $playlists = $xml -> appendChild($playlists);

       $playlist = $xml ->  createElement ("playlist"); 
       $playlist = $playlists -> appendChild ($playlist);

       $track = $xml ->  createElement ("track");
       $track = $playlist -> appendChild ($track);

       $meta = $xml ->  createElement ("meta"); 
       $meta = $track -> appendChild ($meta);

       $xml->formatOutput = true;
       $string_value = $xml->saveXML();
       $xml->save("preview.xml");
```

XML-CODE:

```
<playlists>
    <playlist id="pl1">
        <track href="music/adg3com_bustedchump.mp3" title="Artist 1 - Track 1"     target="http://google.de" rel="covers/cover1.jpg">
            <meta>
                <![CDATA[ <a href="http://google.de" target="_blank">This is an optional text with a link</a> ]]>
            </meta>
        </track>
        <track href="music/adg3com_chuckedknuckles.mp3" title="Artist 2 - Track 2" target="" rel="">
            <meta><![CDATA[This is an optional text]]></meta>
        </track>
    </playlist>
    <playlist id="pl2">
        <track href="http://soundcloud.com/djlewisvi/afrojack-lionheart" title="Afrojack - Lionheart" />
        <track href="music/adg3com_chuckedknuckles.mp3" title="Artist 3 - Track 3" target="" rel="covers/cover1.jpg">
            <meta><![CDATA[This is an optional text]]></meta>
        </track>
        <track href="http://soundcloud.com/radykal/favorites" title="Soundcloud Favorites" />
    </playlist>
</playlists>
```

Comment: <playlists>
  <playlist id="">
    <track href="" title="" />
 <track href="" title="" target="" rel="">
   <meta>
  <![CDATA[This is an optional text]]>
   </meta>
 </track>
 <track href="" title="" />
  </playlist>
  
  
</playlists>

Comment: thats the xml code above.....

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got your question. If it doesn't fit, please let me kno and refine your question!
This is how to create the `href` attribute in the `<track>`node:

```
$track = $xml ->  createElement ("track");
$href = $xml->createAttribute('href');
$href->value="http://soundcloud.com/djlewisvi/afrojack-lionheart";
$track->appendChild($href);
$track = $playlist -> appendChild ($track);
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/uC9J2Y